# C++ Pointers help?

Tags: c++, pointers

I need a little bit of help with using pointers in C++.  Sorry to seem beginner but I really can't quite understand them.  I have read the tutorial on pointers on the cplusplus.com website, so please don't suggest that.

I basically have a variable which holds the name of another variable, and I wish to access that variable through the holder one.  I believe I need to use pointers, correct me if I'm wrong though.

E.g.

```
int a;
string b;

a = 10;
b = "a";
```

I need to access the variable "a" through the contents of variable "b".

Just to put this into better perspective, this is how I am using it:

```
int a;
a = 20;

void getVar(string name) {
    cout << name;
}

getVar("a");
```

But as you can see, on the fifth line, that will just cout the value of name, in this case "a", but I want it to cout the value of the variable which name contains, so I want it to output "20".

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are languages that do what you want to do, but C++ isn't one of them.

Comment: Yeah I know I can do this in PHP, is there any way at all to achieve this, doesn't necessarily have to be with pointers, just the simplest way?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you are trying to accomplish by accessing a variable this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to **associate** a name with a value, consider associative arrays otherwise known as dictionaries and **maps**.  The Standard Template Library has `std::map` that you can use to associate text with a value:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<std::string, int> my_map;

my_map["A"] = 20;

cout << my_map["A"] << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are thinking of is called ([Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29)) which C++ does not support. You can however use pointers to access what is in a variable it points to:

```
int a = 5; //int variable that stores 5
int *b = &a; //int pointer that stores address of a

(*b) = 10; //stores 10 into address that b points to (a)

cout << a; //prints 10
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible in a compiled language (not considering reflection). You might accomplish something similar using a map data structure.

```
theMap["a"] = 20;
```

and a corresponding

```
void getVar(string key){
     cout << theMap[key];
}
```

that can be called with

```
getVar("a");
```

Note that in this extremely simple sample theMap has to be in scope for the function, like in a class or a namespace.

If you use pointers you are just using a level of indirection not at all suited for your example. See Chads answer for instance.

Comment: +1 The map is what I was going to suggest but I was too lazy to type it out.

Answer (score 1):

Theres no real way for you to access variables by name like that unless you create some kind of container class that has a name member that you look up by.  I'm not sure what this has to do with pointers though.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is called "reflection" or "introspection" - the ability to use design-time names for your program's objects (classes, variables, functions, etc) in run time. C++ does not support that out of the box - the design-time names are stripped upon compilation.

There are some libraries that provide that capability in C++; but there are also languages where reflection is is part of the language. Python or JavaScript, for example.

Answer (score 0):

quick fix for outputting integers only:

int a;
a = 20;

void getVar(int name) {
    cout << name;
}

getVar(a);

If you need the function to work for any type of variable, maybe think about some template function.

Edit: Here is the code for the template program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void getVar(T name){
    cout<<name<<endl;
}

int main()
{
string x="hee";
int y=10;
getVar(x);//outputs hee
getVar(y);//outputs 10
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your original answer makes no sense.  Have you compiled and tested it?  Also, the OP needs to reference variables by name, not just value.  All of your code can be replaced by the simple `cout` statement; without using templates.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could suit you:

```
int a = 5;
class b {
public:
   b(int &x) { ref_ = x; }
   int operator()(void) { return ref_; }
private:
   int &ref_;
}

b my_b(a);
my_b() /* -> 5 */;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not use pointers. you're trying to convert a string into an identifier and print it's result, I don't know whether that's possible or not. If you intended using pointer your code should've looked like this:

```
int a = 20;
int* b = &a;
cout << *b;
```